# Build brief module

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I trying to build brief [software](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/research/detect/dbrief). Firstly I create the ./lib/libbrief.so, and secondly I am trying to build  main file.  The makefile which included in .zip file:

```
CC=g++

SOURCES=main.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=main

//#Only enable -msse4.2 on CPUs supporting the POPCNT instruction
CFLAGS = -Wall -DNDEBUG -O3 -march=nocona #-msse4.2 
//#CFLAGS = -Wall -DDEBUG -g -O0 -fno-inline-functions
LDFLAGS = -Wl

//# BRIEF
CFLAGS += -I../brief/include
LDFLAGS += -L../brief/lib -lbrief

//# OpenCV
CFLAGS += `pkg-config opencv --cflags`
LDFLAGS += `pkg-config opencv --libs`

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
$(CC) -g -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

 clean:
rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE) matches.png
```

However I am getting errors, related with opencv. The errors found:

```
g++ -Wl -L../brief/lib -lbrief `pkg-config opencv --libs` main.o -o main
main.o: In function `~BRIEF':
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/../brief/include/brief/BRIEF.hpp:203:     
undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/../brief/include/brief/BRIEF.hpp:204:
undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
main.o: In function `BRIEF':
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/../brief/include/brief/BRIEF.hpp:156:   
undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/../brief/include/brief/BRIEF.hpp:157:
undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.o: In function `TestSampler<signed char>::sampleGaussian(signed char*, int, int)'
main.o: In function `BRIEF':
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/../brief/include/brief/BRIEF.hpp:156: 
undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/../brief/include/brief/BRIEF.hpp:157: 
undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
main.o: In function `TestSampler<signed char>::sampleGaussian(signed char*, int, int)':
main.o: In function `BRIEF::writeTests(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > const&) const':
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/../brief/include/brief/BRIEF.hpp:511: 
undefined reference to `utils::stdoutError(std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, char const*, int, char const*)'
main.o: In function `BRIEF::readTests(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  
std::allocator<char> > const&)':
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/../brief/include/brief/BRIEF.hpp:524: 
undefined reference to `utils::stdoutError(std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, char const*, int, char const*)'
main.o: In function `detectSURF':
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/main.cpp:92: undefined reference to  
`cvCreateMemStorage'
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/main.cpp:101: undefined reference to
`cvExtractSURF'
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/main.cpp:106: undefined reference to    
`cvGetSeqElem'
main.o: In function `timeDescription(int)':
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/main.cpp:201: undefined reference to
`cvLoadImage'
Desktop/asdf/brief_v1.0/test_app/main.cpp:214: undefined reference to 
`cvReleaseImage'
main.o: In function `~BRIEF':
```

What have to do to build proper the main.cpp?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on how you solved the problem because I get the exact same error but I don't really understood the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must list all the object files on the link like *before* the libraries that they use.

See, for example, [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the solution because I have the exact same problem with snake plissken but didn't figure out how to solve it from your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to say: your linker command line will have objects (files that end in `.o`) and libraries (added using the `-l` flag: things like `-lm` etc.)  On the linker command line, all the objects should be listed before any of the libraries.  Also, the order in which the libraries themselves are listed can make a difference: for any library X that uses a feature of library Y, the `-lX` flag should come _before_ the `-lY` flag.  If that doesn't help please create a new question and provide details of your link line and the errors you see.

Comment: Just to be clear, the order that object files are listed in relationship to each other is completely irrelevant.